# Trying to understand the differences between CanActivate and CanActivateChild

Tags: angular, angular2-guards

So, I'm trying to protect the access to several routes by using guards. I'm using the following routes to do so :

```
const adminRoutes : Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ],
    children : [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [ AuthGuardService ],
        children: [
          { path: 'edit', component: DashboardComponent},
          { path: '', component: DashboardComponent}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here's a look at what `AuthGuardService` looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate{

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    console.log("Guarding...");
    return this.sessionValid();
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    console.log("Guarding children...");
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  sessionValid() : boolean {
    //tests
  }

}
```

When I try to access to '/admin' and '/admin/edit' with `canActivate` only (`canActivateChild` is commented) the console displays

```
Guarding...
```

When I remove `canActivate`and bring `canActivateChild`back the console displays

```
Guarding children...
```

When I keep both, it goes back to displaying `Guarding...`.
So, my question is what's the purpose of having `canActivateChild` when `canActivate`protects both the root element and the children ?

PS : I get it that `canActivateChild` runs before the child route is activated. But what are the benefits of that ? Isn't keeping only one of them sufficient ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Both are important because you may have differing requirements where a user can get to the root component, but may not meet conditions for child components.

Example:  You could have a situation where a user must be authenticated to navigate to the root component, but must have permission 'x' to get to child components.  In cases like this, `canActivateChild` saves a lot of typing from having to add `canActivate` guards to each of the children.

EDIT:

For example, you may have an Admin Module where all routes need to be guarded against unauthorized entry:

```
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ],
    children : [
      {
        path: '', component: ...,
      },
      {
        path: 'manage-users', component: ...,
      },
      {
        path: 'manage-roles', component: ...,
      }
    ]
  }
```

This would need to be protected from the top down.  No unauthorized access to any of the routes, including the root and children.  In this situation `canActivate` at the root level works great to protect everything.

But you may also have times where you have a Feature module where only certain children need to be guarded:

```
  {
    path: 'featureA',
    component: ...,
    canActivateChild: [ AuthGuardService ],
    children : [
      {
        path: 'manage-feature', component: ...,
      },
      {
        path: 'manage-members', component: ...,
      }
    ],
    {path: 'featureB', component: ...}
  }
```

In this situation, maybe all users need to get to the root components 'featureA' and 'featureB', but only certain users need to be able to navigate to the child routes of 'featureA'.  In this case it is easier to use one guard at the root level to protect the children, but not the root itself. The alternative is to put `canActivate` guards on each child route, which could get tedious.

It really all depends upon your requirements, but it can be nice to have both options of `canActivate` and `canActivateChild`.

Comment: Can't we just use canActivate instead of canActivateChild then ?

Comment: Maybe, it depends on your requirements.  The example I gave above may be a bit too contrived.  `canActivateChild` is run before each child route is activated.  You can indeed protect a root component an all children with `canActivate`, but you may have children certain users don't need to see when they need to be able to see the root component.  For example, you could sprinkle in some Admin components into a Feature module that most or all users need to get to the root of, but not necessarily children of certain routes.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, the `CanActivate` is used to restrict access from a certain path and all the sub-paths and `CanActivateChild` is used to restrict access to a specific group inside the `CanActivate` path.

Example:

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  children : [
    {
      path: 'books', component: ...,
    },
    {
      path: 'authors', component: ...,
    },
    {
      path: 'payments',
      canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
      children: [
        {
          path: 'list', component: ...
        },
        {
          path: 'list/:id', component: ...
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Because you need two types of validations, you cannot have two `canActivate` methods, so you need the `canActivateChild` for checking the permision inside the `canActivate` path. Obviously, you can create a different guard service (`AuthGuardForChildrenRoutes`) and still use `canActivate` method, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 1):

| sr no. | CanActivate | CanActivateChild |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | It prevents access to the parent route which also includes access to all child routes | we can access the parent route but if required we can choose to block a particular child route by using canActivateChild |
| 2 | Yes you can achieve CanActivateChild behavior by applying CanActivate to all the child routes | just adding CanActivateChild at parent route saves a lot of time and it is more convenient |

Now this was the basic difference between canActivate and canActivatedchild

here is the situation where these two could be used

**Figure** : ***path to illustrate the difference between CanActivate & CanActivateChild***

 [image: canactivatedchild vs canactive example]

 **CanActivate**: Computer department student can not access other departments

 **CanActivateChild**: Computer department student have access to computer department(which is parent in this case) but cannot access one child of computer department i.e. faculty role access

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have called canActivate inside canActivateChild, hence both the guards are getting called when you are traversing among child routes. If you were to have different authentication logic inside both the guards, your canActivate guard won't execute while traversing among child routes.